# Git init in wrong directory? How to recover? (theoretical situation)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, directory, git

This is completely theoretical, but I'm new to Git and Linux so I want to know.

If I accidentally manage to do `git init` inside e.g Desktop or Home directory, how to prevent any possible disaster from happening?

`git init` creates hidden `.git` directory where it's config-files are so is it just so simple to remove this hidden directory?

Would the directory it was in become "normal" again instead of git master branch?

Or would removing .git cause some problems? Like the directory trying to identify itself as git repository but cannot find the configs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `git init` in a directory which isn’t already a git repository, removing `.git` will reverse all the effects of `git init` without any other side-effects.

Comment: Figured as much. Makes sense since there are no other directories connected to git. (outside of git install directory)

Comment: Yes, the nice thing about Git (as I understand it) is all of the files managed by it (for the current working branch) are just regular files on the filesystem. Git itself doesn't go anything but track files and metadata about them as well as the same for files in all of the other branches for that repository. It only actively changes those files when you switch between branches.